# ansible verify the k8s deployment succeed

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubectl

I am using ansible k8s module to do the pod deployment, but unfortunately, I did not find a way to use `wait` and `wait_condition` correctly.

so I tried use the `until` and `retry` to implement another waiting

each time after you run the playbook, after you use k8s module to do the deployment, until NewReplicaSetAvailable shows up in the deployment within 2 minutes(60 * 2s), otherwise the deployment failed.

In case you need to verify the deployment result, I write down here.

```
    - name: Verify the deploy result
      shell: "kubectl -n kube-system get deployment coredns --output=jsonpath='{.status.conditions[*].reason}'"
      register: deploy_res
      until: "'NewReplicaSetAvailable' in deploy_res.stdout"
      retries: 60
      delay: 2
```

Answer (score 4):

the module `k8s` gives you not the status of the Deployment. For the status of a Deployment (or any other resource) you should use the module `k8s_info`. Then you can do your check on this task.

Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create a Service object from an inline definition
    k8s:
      state: present
      definition:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: example
          namespace: default
        spec:
          replicas: 3
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: example-nginx
          template:
            metadata:
              labels:
                app: example-nginx
            spec:
              containers:
              - image: nginx
                name: nginx
  - name: check if deployment is ready
    k8s_info:
      kind: Deployment
      label_selectors: 
        - app = example-nginx
    register: output_info
    until: output_info.resources | json_query('[*].status.conditions[?reason==`NewReplicaSetAvailable`][].status') | select ('match','True') | list | length == 1
    delay: 2
    retries: 5
```

For the `until` filter there are certainly better solutions, but I have solved it this way for a similar use case. The `until` filter checks if there is a condition with the reason `NewReplicaSetAvailable` and it must be `True`. If that happens, the length is equal to `1`

Answer (score 2):

Validation can be done like number of replica set are equal or not, imgae updated on all pods.

```
    - name: Add a deployment
      k8s:
        definition:
          apiVersion: apps/v1
          kind: Deployment
          metadata:
            name: wait-deploy
            namespace: "{{ wait_namespace }}"
          spec:
            replicas: 3
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                app: "{{ k8s_pod_name }}"
            template: "{{ k8s_pod_template }}"
        wait: yes
        wait_timeout: "{{ k8s_wait_timeout | default(omit) }}"
      vars:
        k8s_pod_name: wait-deploy
        k8s_pod_image: gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:1
        k8s_pod_ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: http
            protocol: TCP

      register: deploy

    - name: Check that deployment wait worked
      assert:
        that:
          - deploy.result.status.availableReplicas == deploy.result.status.replicas

    - name: Update a deployment
      k8s:
        definition:
          apiVersion: apps/v1
          kind: Deployment
          metadata:
            name: wait-deploy
            namespace: "{{ wait_namespace }}"
          spec:
            replicas: 3
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                app: "{{ k8s_pod_name }}"
            template: "{{ k8s_pod_template }}"
        wait: yes
        wait_timeout: "{{ k8s_wait_timeout | default(omit) }}"
      vars:
        k8s_pod_name: wait-deploy
        k8s_pod_image: gcr.io/kuar-demo/kuard-amd64:2
        k8s_pod_ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            name: http
            protocol: TCP
      register: update_deploy

    # It looks like the Deployment is updated to have the desired state *before* the pods are terminated
    # Wait a couple of seconds to allow the old pods to at least get to Terminating state
    - name: Avoid race condition
      pause:
        seconds: 2

    - name: Get updated pods
      k8s_info:
        api_version: v1
        kind: Pod
        namespace: "{{ wait_namespace }}"
        label_selectors:
          - app=wait-deploy
        field_selectors:
          - status.phase=Running
      register: updated_deploy_pods
      until: updated_deploy_pods.resources[0].spec.containers[0].image.endswith(':2')
      retries: 6
      delay: 5

    - name: Check that deployment wait worked
      assert:
        that:
          - deploy.result.status.availableReplicas == deploy.result.status.replicas
```

Mention solution can be found on kubernetes Ansible repo  [k8s_waiter](https://github.com/ansible-collections/kubernetes.core/blob/fd61f8b15d889c6b80866d62770c9c712cbbc98e/tests/integration/targets/k8s_waiter/tasks/main.yml)